# Unit testing methods declared in class extensions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I was curious regarding the following things. As I have various methods declared in class extensions, is it possible to unit test them using XCTest?

For example, given a class extension containing method foo:

```
@interface FooClass()

-(NSString*)foo;

@end
```

how can I test foo: in a test class?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need testing inside methods as you maybe change it more often in process implementation. Testing need from *.h files, but if you need you can create category for test. Also you can use runtime (for example — performSelector)

*RSFooClass.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface RSFooClass : NSObject
@end
```

*RSFooClass.m*

```
#import "RSFooClass.h"


@implementation RSFooClass

- (NSString *)foo {
    return @"Hello world";
}

- (NSInteger)sum:(NSInteger)a with:(NSInteger)b {
    return a + b;
}

@end
```

*RSFooClassTest.m*

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "RSFooClass.h"


@interface RSFooClass (Testing)

- (NSString *)foo;
- (NSInteger)sum:(NSInteger)a with:(NSInteger)b;

@end


@interface RSFooClassTest : XCTestCase

@property (strong, nonatomic) RSFooClass *foo;

@end


@implementation RSFooClassTest

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    self.foo = [[RSFooClass alloc] init];
}

- (void)testFoo {
    NSString *result = [self.foo foo];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, @"Hello world");
}

- (void)testSumWith {
    NSInteger a = 1;
    NSInteger b = 3;
    NSInteger result = [self.foo sum:a with:b];
    NSInteger expected = a + b;
    XCTAssertEqual(result, expected);
}

@end
```